# Vue Reactivity, How to Improve nested component dependency structure

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a parent search component that loads data based on search param changes, and it has a child component basically created to separate complicated logic e.g , which fires events and passes data to parent based on changes to state e.g (could be a selector, input change, etc...). what I want is to wait for both the child component to fire its initial events and the parent component as well and then call the function in watch for search params.
currently this code is making two request I want to wait for the child event to be fired to make it a single call, or if there is an alternative solution to this kind of architecture I would appreciate it.

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld @id-change="(e) => (searchParams.userIds = e)" />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorldVue from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld: HelloWorldVue,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchParams: {
        userIds: [],
        sort: "ID",
        sortType: "DESC",
      },
    };
  },
  watch: {
    searchParams: {
      handler(newVal) {
        console.log("hello", newVal);
        this.loadDataFromBackend(newVal);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  created() {
    //some logic would change search params here
    //based on which page I am coming from, 
    //or I may have route params etc...
    this.searchParams.sortType = "ASEC";
  },
  methods: {
    loadDataFromBackend(params) {
      //an api call here
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This the child component that loads the Ids and the passes it to parrent.

```
<template>
  <div ></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },

  created() {
    //this event does not hapeeing immedialty
    setTimeout(this.loadIdsFromBackend, 5000);
  },
  methods: {
    async loadIdsFromBackend() {
      this.$emit("id-change", [1, 2, 3, 4]);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I want a way to bring this to a single call but at the moment its call the loadFromBackendFunction twice, yeah I the state is change twice so therefore two calls but I want an alternative solution.

Comment: In the handler check that all the required parts are present in `newVal` and only call backend when they're there.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for. Is it [debounce](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/)? Note asking for recommendations is *off-topic* on [SO]. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first call comes from this part

```
  created() {
    this.searchParams.sortType = "ASEC";
  },
```

It triggers the watcher and causes the first call to `loadDataFromBackend`

But why do you set `sortType` to `DESC` in `data()` and change it right after creating to `ASEC`?

This does not make any sense to me. I would just put `ASEC` as default value.

Comment: thats just an example, I keep some of these search params in router on reload on I want to assign them